# How to upload files to google drive from firebase storage using Apps Script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-storage

I have a mobile app uploading img to firebase storage. How can I use Google Apps script to transfer the image to google drive?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have an SDK for Google Apps script. Luckily Firebase SDKs provide a fairly thin wrapper around the underlying Google Cloud Storage product, so for this scenario you can actually use any approach that works for the latter too. For example, this article seems promising [Upload Files from Google Drive to Google Cloud Storage with Google Apps Script](https://www.labnol.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage) as do these [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=upload+from+apps+script+to+cloud+storage).